# Excel XML: Where can I find documentation for syntax?

Tags: excel, xml

I have scoured the ends of the internet the past few hours trying to find some documentation on Excel XML, so I can custom build spreadsheets within a webapp to be exported, but.. it doesn't seem to exist anywhere?

For instance, within the XML, there are  tags, and I'm trying to understand what these are? I'm ultimately trying to figure out how to autofocus on 'Sheet 2' within the document and avoid sheet 1 altogether(since it's hidden by default). Even though Sheet 1 is hidden, it still opens on Sheet 1. I need to avoid utilizing VB for this and was hoping there may be some XML tag or syntax that could focus on sheet 2.

Thanks for any info.

Comment: What were your research results? Please provide links and why they don't help. If VBA does the trick, then it might be part of the Excel-file - in XML, too (do a diff on the XML and see what is added to reproduce within your app) ️

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using Python, this [`xlsxwriter` tutorial](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_macros.html) explains how to add VBA macros to your workbook.

#### Hiding a worksheet and activating another

This solution in Python is assembled from 2 examples of *XlsxWriter Documentation*:

1. [Tutorial 1: Create a simple XLSX file](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/tutorial01.html)
2. [Example: Hiding Worksheets](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_hide_sheet.html?highlight=hide%20sheet)

```py
import xlsxwriter

# Create a workbook and add a worksheet.
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Expenses01.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Some data we want to write to the worksheet.
expenses = (
    ['Rent', 1000],
    ['Gas',   100],
    ['Food',  300],
    ['Gym',    50],
)

# Start from the first cell. Rows and columns are zero indexed.
row = 0
col = 0

# Iterate over the data and write it out row by row.
for item, cost in (expenses):
    worksheet.write(row, col,     item)
    worksheet.write(row, col + 1, cost)
    row += 1

# Write a total using a formula.
worksheet.write(row, 0, 'Total')
worksheet.write(row, 1, '=SUM(B1:B4)')


worksheet2 = workbook.add_worksheet()
# Note, you can't hide the the "active" worksheet, which generally is the
# first worksheet, since this would cause an Excel error. So, in order to hide
# the first sheet you will need to activate another worksheet:
worksheet2.activate()
# Hide Sheet1. It won't be visible until it is unhidden in Excel.
worksheet.hide()

workbook.close()
```

When opening the resulting XLSX file in LibreOffice, "Sheet1" is hidden whereas "Sheet2" is shown, active and focused.